# JQuery execute function when enter is pressed in a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

```
        $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                $("#submitButton").click(); 
            }
        });
```

Thats what I have to execute my function when enter is pressed anywhere in a page, but that conflicts with my `dropdown list` keyboard navigation .

```
<div class="form-group" id="contractGroup">
                <label for="inputContract" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Contract Type <b>*</b></label>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                    <div class="input-group" id="contractPicker">
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Full-time</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Part-time</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" ID="inputContract" placeholder="Full time, Part time"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When trying to tab through `dropdown list`, you have to use enter to select item, which executes my function at same time as well, which I dont want.

I know its possible to do function for each `textbox` checking if enter was pressed while that `textbox` have focus, but I have over 20+ and would rather avoid that. And I know that I can use `asp:panel defaultbutton` but that ignores my jquery function and calls codebehind and not jquery function as I have 2 `linking buttons` act as one and one of them cannot be `asp:button` which is needed for `asp:panel`.

Another solution is to somehow to make `dropdown list` treated differently and not as "current page". I am using bootstrap `datepicker` and while keyboard navigating through calendar popup, I can use enter without calling my function.
If its possible I would love to have single function that detects if enter was pressed on any `textbox` on a page.
Cheers

Comment: Just bind it to all your textboxes. As is, even if you're not focused on the element, and hit enter, you're going to submit the form

Comment: Use `$('input[type=text]')` instead of `$(document)`?

Comment: @user3557327, that's what I get for not knowing javascript and JQuery, just used $('input[type=text]') in another function and didnt even though about using it for this one, cheers works like a charm. 
If you post this as an answer ill accept it.

Comment: What does this question have to do with Bootstrap specifically?

Comment: @MattD not much, but it was one of my imagined solutions, changing how  dropdown list is treated on page and for that I would probably need to change something on bootstrap side.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an id to the dropdown div and have a click listener tied to it to prevent it from bubbling up. Something like...

```
$("#dropdown-list").keypress(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

Comment: Cheers, already got it worked with @user3557327 suggestion, but this seems that it can be useful someday as well.